# Como pegar informações de um option com Jquery/Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Esse select é um ajax, que depois recebo e coloco em um modal. Estava precisando passar alguns valores por pelo select para depois usar eles na função addAtributo ativado pelo Click de um botão

```
        <select class="form-control selectDropdown" id='listaAtributo'>
            <?
            foreach ($atributos as $ind => $v) {
                ?>
                <optgroup label="<?= $v['atributo']; ?>">
                    <option data-chave='<?= $v['atributo'];?>' data-id='<?= $v['id'];?>'><?= $v['valor']; ?></option>
                </optgroup>
            <? } ?>
        </select>
```

Oque eu já tentei mas não de certo, apenas consigo pegar o val(). Tambem tentei passar os valores com onChange no select mas como os valores estão dentro de um foreach não funcionou, apenas o this.value.

```
    function addAtributo() {
        var _atributo = $('#listaAtributo').val();
        var _id = $('#listaAtributo').attr("id");
        var _id = $('#listaAtributo').attr("data-chave");
        var _id = $('#listaAtributo').data("chave");
        var _listaAtributoChave = $('#listaAtributo').children(":selected").attr("id");
    }
```

Como prosseguir?

Agradeço a atenção

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer pegar apenas o `data-id` do `option` que está selecionado, bastaria fazer (sem JQuery):

```
window.document.querySelector("#listaAtributo").selectedOptions[0].dataset.id;
```

*O `.selectedOptions` pertence ao [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement). O `[0]` é utilizado porque o `select` suporta o `multiple` e assumo que este não é o caso, obviamente. Você também pode usar o `.selectedIndex` em combinação com o `.options` também.*

Por exemplo:

```js
let button = window.document.querySelector("button");
let output = window.document.querySelector("output");

button.addEventListener("click", function(_) {
  output.value = window.document.querySelector("#listaAtributo").selectedOptions[0].dataset.id;
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control selectDropdown" id='listaAtributo'>
  <optgroup label="ATTR-1">
    <option data-chave='ATTR-1' data-id='ID-1'>Valor-1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="ATTR-2">
    <option data-chave='ATTR-2' data-id='ID-2'>Valor-2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<button>SALVAR</button>

<output></output>
```